# File handling with functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I got this code that is supposed to sort a dictionary within a json file alphabetically by key:

```
import json

def values(infile,outfile):
    with open(infile):
        data=json.load(infile)
        data=sorted(data)
        with open(outfile,"w"):
            json.dump(outfile,data)

values("values.json","values_out.json")
```

And when I run it I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'
```

I'm pretty sure I messed something up when I made the function but I don't know what.

EDIT: This is what the json file contains:

```
{"two": 2,"one": 1,"three": 3}
```

Comment: `with open(infile) as file_handle:` and then `json.load(file_handle)`.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252740/3757232

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the strings `infile` and `outfile` in your `json` calls, you need to use the file description instance, that you get using `as` keyword

```
def values(infile,outfile):
    with open(infile) as fic_in:
        data = json.load(fic_in)
        data = sorted(data)
        with open(outfile,"w") as fic_out:
            json.dump(data, fic_out)
```

You can group, `with` statements

```
def values(infile, outfile):
    with open(infile) as fic_in, open(outfile, "w") as fic_out:
        json.dump(sorted(json.load(fic_in)), fic_out)
```

Comment: Do I also have to specify the file path in this instance?

Comment: @Score-6 Goad isn"t to make be happy at all, and you're free to write what you want, you intrigated me with your full caps message, I just looked at it ;)

Comment: @grokestray what do you mean ?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to assign the file you opened to a variable. In your current code you open a file, but then try to load the filename rather than the actual file.  This code should run because you assign the file object reference to my_file.

```
import json 
def values(infile,outfile):
    with open(infile) as my_file:
        data=json.load(my_file)
        data=sorted(data)
        with open(outfile,"w"):
            json.dump(outfile,data)

values("values.json","values_out.json")
```

Comment: Now I'm getting AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'write'. I wrote it exactly as you did